# assembly ARM: get array element from C header

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, arm

I'm very new to Assembly and now I'm trying to figure out how do arrays work.

I have .c file, where I declare a dynamic array and then pass it to .s file using header.

my_main.c:

```
#include "my.h"
...

int *arr;
arr = (int*) malloc( 10 * sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr[i] = i;
}
printf("%d\n", getFirst(arr));
```

header.h:

```
int getFirst(int *arr);
```

and then in my.s:

```
# here I need to somehow get the first element of the array
bx lr
```

Now it returns the same pointer that I would get if I'd do `printf("%d", arr)`, but how do I get the `arr[0]` within my.s?

The only thing I tried so far is just

```
mov r0, r0[0]
```

but it makes an error.

Comment: _"an error"_ **What** error? By the way, `r0[0]` looks pretty weird in assembly code. It ought to be written as `[r0,#0]` (or just `[r0]`).

Comment: Error: garbage following instruction -- `mov r0,r0[0]'

Comment: Well, use valid syntax, like the one I suggested.

Comment: both variants give "immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `mov r0,[r0]'" / "immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `mov r0,[r0,#0]'"

Comment: Oh right, `ldr`, not `mov`. In ARM assembly `mov` is used for moving between registers or loading immediates. To load from memory you need `ldr` or one of its variants.

Comment: alright, if i do ldr r0, [r2, #0], I get the first element, but if I do #1 or whatever else not 0 instead, I get weird numbers. how do I get other elements properly?

Comment: Each element is 4 bytes. In ARM assembly you're specifying offsets, not inidices. So to get the second element you would use `[r0, #4]`.

Comment: On some ARM CPUs/modes you can use also barrel shifter to multiply the index value by 4 (`sizeof(int)`), like this: `ldr r0, [r0, #1, LSL #2] == ldr r0, [r0, #4]` .. doesn't make sense with immediate to use longer syntax, but if you have index in second register, it may be handy to recall there's the barrel shifter unit on ARM, sometimes allowing you to keep index in "human" numbers, not multiplied by data size.